# How do I create url preview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, preview

I want to show preview of any url in android when I share it (like it is shown in facebook or whatsapp). the preview must contain an image from the webpage and small description of the link. I thought of picking up information from metadata and favicon, but favicon is very small in size and metadata is not always present (for example, in Quora u don't get information about the question in the metadata). Sorry for my bad english and lack of clearity.

Comment: The question is not duplicate. This question is asking how to show url preview in android and the original question link provided how the url link of the website show the preview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout this [Rich Link Preview](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/RichLinkPreview) Library which does the same you are seeking for.

[image: Rich Link Preview]

You can import the library using Gradle :

Simply add the dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.github.ponnamkarthik:richlinkpreview:1.0.9'
}
```

Comment: Getting    `> Could not find com.leocardz:link-preview:2.0.0.` after upgrading my target and compileSdk versions to 29

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: I think i should change library

Comment: @HenockBongi I have updated the library with a newer one.