# Displaying preview of any URL link entered by the user like Skype?

Tags: android, url

I would like to display the URL preview entered by the user like skype app in . For example if i am entering a youtube url in the skype app to other person , it is automatically displaying the thumbnail preview of that URL entered by the user.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUgRDYehv0M

When i have entered above url means.. Skype automatically showing the thumbnail preview of that link like below:

[image]

Like skype i would like to do in android. Whenever if user enters any url means.. i need to show the preview of an url..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leocardz.link.preview&feature=search_result

Refered above app.. anyother help or guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Hey Rotomac you can find from here.
https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2755

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create url preview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917503/how-do-i-create-url-preview-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the library using Gradle :

Simply add the repository to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}
```

And you can use the artifacts like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3' // required
    compile 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.1@aar'
}
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439017/preview-a-url-in-android-the-way-facebook-does-before-you-post-a-link-link-pre) link for more details.

Comment: hi @Mitesh compile 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.1@aar' gives error

Comment: sorry I forgot to update it's solved I used your solution only. thank you +1